# How to limit the characters in input field in crystal report

Tags: crystal-reports-2008

I am using crystal report 2008, i have a report and that has a input field called "Departure_no".

In this input field we can type maximum of four departure_no (Eg: 2345,234,2345,23456), if it exceeds this limit(more than 4 numbers-can count with 3 commas(,)), this input field should not allow to type further.

Is there any way to achieve this by formula or something else by crystal report??

Thanks in advance!!

Priya

Comment: are you using any .net coding?

Comment: No... just crystal report oly...

Answer (score 0):

try below

use alerts to show the message: I am showing on a database field

Go to `Report--> Alert --> Create or modify alert`

When a window is opened provide the following:

1. required name
2. Required message
3. Condtion when alert need to be displayed

You can give condition as

```
if Length(databasefield)> 4   //you need only 4 chars hence this condition
then true
else false
```

Click ok.

Now you will get message

Let me know of you are looking for something different

Comment: i used as u mentioned above. :( but it doesnt link with report.. if i give less than 4 inputs also it poped up.

Comment: can you post your formula

Comment: if length(totext({Command.DEPARTURE_NO}))>4
then
true
else
false

Comment: Departure_No column actually a interger ,so it showed the error to convert text, that is why i added the convert(totext) there.. And in message part i just gave, "should not enter more than 4 Departure_Nos"

Comment: if length({?SP_DEPARTURE_NO})>4 then
true
else
false

Comment: /*Im using above condition to get alert */ I will type in the i/p field as (Eg: 3345,3345,4345,3345) if exceeds this 4 nos, msg shd dislay

Comment: If you use a parameter I guess you won't be able to achieve this... normally this works for database fields..

Comment: It worked for me for database fields why are you unable to get this... are you doing anything different

Comment: I have tested again and its working for me... I don't understand why its not working for you.... You need to enter the data and refresh the report the you will get the alert displayed as a popup on your screen... and your condition for alert is correct

Comment: yes, i need to restrict the parameter field only..that condition should work when typing input in parameter field

Comment: I don't think it works during typing but you will get the display after typing and click on `Ok`

Comment: no problem you are welcome... hope my answer helps :)